# Symfony 3 - The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

Tags: csrf, symfony

So first of all, I already tried to find another topic related to my issue as it already exists a lot :p.

But I can't figure out why Symfony keeps telling me that ... :

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form
```

I'm using a regular form, and the weird part is that it works on another computer but not on this one (the files are the same except the cache/session/log files).

- I use both **{{ form_rest(form) }}** and **{{ form_end(form) }}** twig variables.  I increased both **max_input_vars** and **upload_max_filesize** properties of my php.ini .
- My database is up to date.
- The hidden _token input is displayed in the html.
- I cleared my app and browser caches.
- Since this is a local website, I just granted all my folders/files with the 777 permission..

EDIT : If I replace (app/config/config.yml) :

```
save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

with

```
save_path: ~
```

It works..  But I have no idea of what are the consequences of this?  Sessions are stored based on the php.ini file right?  So can I use this setting instead of the previous one without any problems?

Otherwise, I have absolutely no idea of what could cause the error.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Just for others - I had upgraded PHP on my server and done a reload on php-fpm and then this error appeared when it otherwise had worked prior. I had to do a full restart of php-fpm, not just a reload, but then this error went away :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

should be fine. Just make sure that your `var/sessions` folder exists and it is writable

```
mkdir -p var/sessions
chmod 755 var/sessions
```

The same must be true for `var/cache` and `var/logs`.

Comment: I already tried that, and it's really strange because it works on my office computer but not at home (both running vagrant (scotchbox) on a mac, I'm just not quite sure my vagrant configuration is the very same on both machines but I don't really know how it'd be related :x).  

I'll still try with your command lines when I get back home, thx ;)

Comment: Good... as you are at it, please check what user is owning those folders too.

Comment: On your Vagrant box, use a path outside the shared folder and you should be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same pb

1st i worked with xampp that is using apache(works fine -no changes required)

2nd i moved on ubuntu with nginx(here was the pb)

i deleted `sessions/cache ->nothing`

instead i changed **"save_path: ~ "** and it's work

Comment: where did you delete sessions/cache?